# Are CaOCl2 and Ca(OCl)2 same or different?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Are the two compounds same? Also, which one is considered bleaching powder? Please explain their differences on the basis of their structures also.

Comment: Apart that the formulae are certainly different.

Comment: People do not hesitate to ask questions like "Are 1 and 2 the same or different ?", if it is in context of chemistry.

Comment: CaOCl2 is incorrect notation as it implies Calcium in +4 oxidation state which does not occur.

Comment: @Waylander As a summary formula, it would be correct, unless IUPAC prefers other element order, like CaCl2O.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{CaOCl2}$ is a **calcium chloride hypochlorite**. There are two different types of anions: *chloride* $\ce{Cl-}$ and *hypochlorite* $\ce{ClO-}$. So its structure is:

[image]

$\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ is a **calcium hypochlorite** (also called *bleaching powder* or *bleach*). There is only one type of anions: *hypochlorites* $\ce{ClO-}$. So its structure is:

[image]

Comment: They are not covalent compounds. Note that bleaching powder is complex mixture of calcium hydroxide and basic calcium chlorides and hypochlorites. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hypochlorite

Comment: These "structures" are nonsense and have little to do with reality.

Comment: Of course, these structures are drawn by me just for clarity.

Comment: Could you please send here the right structures of these compounds?